# Can a desktop use a motherboard Ethernet port and a USB to Ethernet dongle at the same time

Tags: windows-7, networking, usb, ethernet

I have a computer I'm trying to connect to our network, but the motherboard Ethernet port is connected to some sort of security camera system. I'd rather not go unplugging systems I know nothing about. So my question is, if I leave that connection in place and add a USB to Ethernet adapter, can the computer manage both connections while using the USB to connect to the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that this is an IP camera, this can definitely be done.   You simply need to ensure that the camera network is on a different subnet to the network the USB Ethernet adaptor connects to - ie the IP address ranges are different.

(This answer assumes the Camera network interface does not make use of a default gateway - this is a reasonable, but possibly incorrect assumption.  If it does use a default gateway you would need to stop this happening, which may be trivial or quite involved depending on the setup and reason for the gateway)

Comment: That's perfectly reasonable, thanks for the answer!